# Mysql SET and querying subset with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, set

I have a basic mysql database and using php as a web service to my android application. There are 21 categories in my app and I am storing them in a column as a Mysql SET in the database. An article can have multiple categories.

I let the users to choose one or more categories. Right now I am sending all the selected categories as a hardcoed "string" value and concatenating all of them like follows.

SELECT * FROM ........... WHERE cats LIKE '%$cat1%' OR cats LIKE '%$cat2%'

As you can guess this is a very low process.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I assume you mean "slow process". What process is slow? the query execution time or creating the query?

Comment: I just know that php executing this Query and other things is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Make a categories table, an article table, AND a union table only with foreign keys, to locate an article in multiple categories.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way to do this would be to redesign your schema a bit to create three tables: `Article`, `Category`, and `ArticleCategories`.  The first two tables are just what you expect (Articles - category data, and the contents of your set).  The third table will map unique articleID-categoryID relationships.  Then, it's a simple matter of joining:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles JOIN ArticleCategories USING (articleID)
    JOIN Categories USING (categoryID)
WHERE
    catName LIKE '%$cat1%' OR catName LIKE '%$cat2%'
```

It's also a bit unclear to me why you need to use `LIKE` since you seem to imply that the users have to select categories that you give them rather than type them in.  If you're not using `LIKE`, then you can just use `IN` for the category list.

Comment: I have used FIND_IN_SET() and it is still slow. I guess I will change the schema. But stil, is there a way to do that with sets?